# Facebook SDK Android AppEventsLogger NullPointerException on flush

Tags: java, android, facebook, nullpointerexception, event-tracking

I integrated the current FacebookSDK for Android v3.5 for tracking purposes.
You can track app installs by calling
    com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(context, YOUR_APP_ID);

So far no problems, i can see these events are shown on the facebook dashboard.
When it comes to track events or purchase events, facebook recomments doing the following:

```
m_fbAppEventsLogger = com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.newLogger(applicationcontext);
m_fbAppEventsLogger.logPurchase(BigDecimal.valueOf(4.99), Currency.getInstance("USD"));
```

It seems that the purchase events get flushed immediately, which results in

```
09-22 15:10:04.680: D/com.facebook.AppEventsLogger(31691): Caught unexpected exception while flushing: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

If i try to send a custom event, the same error occurs if the facebook SDK decides to flush the events in its queue.

I found nothing for this behavior, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution for this

Answer (score 3):

I initialise the Facebook SDK differently to the examples given in their documentation.

Facebook recommend that you define `meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId` in `AndroidManifest.xml` and  hardcode a value for `facebook_app_id` in `strings.xml`. If you are using source control these files are usually checked in and, as a general rule, I don't like to commit my keys to remote repositories.

I pull in a string resource, named `facebook_app_id`, from an external file with my gradle build. I then define the `facebook_app_id` manually when I initialise the Facebook SDK rather than relying on the library to find it.

**Initialise Facebook SDK**

Initialise Facebook SDK (enables tracking of install events):

```
private void initialiseFacebook(Application application) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(application);
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(application, application.getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
}
```

**Initialise Facebook AppEventsLogger**

Subsequently, I wanted to log some [Facebook App Events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/android). I could see that my install events were being successfully tracked by Facebook Analytics. However, I each time I attempted to log an event the following error was returned:

> Caught unexpected exception while flushing:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

For me the solution was to again manually define the `facebook_app_id` in my method call to create an AppEventsLogger. This solved the problem for me.

```
AppEventsLogger.newLogger(application, application.getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
```

**Also: Enable SDK Debugging:**

I found it very helpful to have more detailed logs from the Facebook SDK while I was troubleshooting this problem. You can configure it with the code below:

```
FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.REQUESTS);
```

This method also has the advantage of letting you use different a facebook_app_id for each build type and/or flavour.

Answer (score 2):

you should add
    `<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>`
to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: That does not remove the NPE for me.

Comment: Which Facebook-Android-SDK-Version are you using?
I have also a constant with the same id here:
`AppEventsLogger.newLogger(getApplicationContext(), Consts.FACEBOOK_APP_ID);`